# How to make FedAuth cookies unique for each application in on solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, wif

I am using System.IdentityModel and claim based authentication for authenticating my MVC app.
In login page after checking username and password I uses this approach to create FedAuth Cookie(s) :

```
   var token = new SessionSecurityToken(MyCustomClaimsPrincipal.GetInstance(username, roles,claims)            );       
   token.IsPersistent=rememberMe;

   var sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
   sam.IsReferenceMode = true;
   sam.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token);
```

Everything works fine but the problem is when I use exactly the same approach in 2 other applications in the same solution that is going to be published on different domains; But in localhost FedAuth Cookies conflict with each other. When I log in to one app, cookies are not valid in the other apps and I should login again.

In fact I can work with only one app at the same time.
I think it is only on localhost and there is no problem on different domains after publish. But I prefere to make the FedAuth cookie unique for each application in one solution. Is it possible? and how?
Maybe it is possible with Context or ContextId in constructor of SessionSequrityToken. But I did not found any example about that. I do not know what to send as context and contextId params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sessionAuthenticationModule has a member called cookiehandler (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.sessionauthenticationmodule_members.aspx) That cookiehandler has a name which is the name of the cookie.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.cookiehandler_members.aspx

You can also do what you're doing in config 

`<system.identityModel.services> 
    <federationConfiguration> 
          <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" name="yourcookienamehere"/> 
    ...`

</system.identityModel.services>

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much. It works but I also have another problem. While I am logged in (local), each time I build solution the cookies are not valid anymore and I need to login again. Do you know why? Maybe I should set expire time of cookies to session but It is not possible. It always has a default expire time of 12 hours if I do not set it!

Comment: I guess this has to do with the fact that the sessions has expired on the "server".  Your previous session no longer exists on the web server and therefore your session security token is no longer valid.  I think this is the normal behaviour.  The STS might decide to keep you signed in, in which case your local host app will automatically get a new security token after a small redirect to the signin page of the STS.  Which STS do you use ?